# Tabindex Dosent hide the li tag content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWxph.jpg)I want focus on li tab when the user click on the link

```html
<li id="secondli"><a onclick="showscndbox();" id="secondlink" >How  can I upload with my membership?</a></li>// tab to be clicked


<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" id="secondbox" style="display:none;" >
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pro-box-in-faq" > 
    content to hide or show
  </div>
</div>
```

There are 19 `li` tags, i want to make the `li` tag focusable on click and let other div  hide

```js
function showthrdbox()   {
  //ta
  document.getElementById("thirdbox").style.display = "block";

  $("#thrdli").attr('tabindex',2).focus();

  document.getElementById("secondli").removeAttr('tabindex');
  document.getElementById("secondbox").style.display = "none";
}
```

This script focus the clicked `li` tag but doesn't let the another `div` hide. Please let me know the solution.

Comment: Why do you change the tabindex? It has nothing to do with the visibility of elements.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider When i added the tabindex attribute to focus it stopped hiding the previous li tag's content

Answer (score 0):

Is this what u want? the target li will be focused, and other lis will be hidden?
if so, checked the following code:

```
function showscndbox(e) {
    var anchor = e.target;
    var p = anchor.parentNode;
    var pp = p.parentNode;
    for (var i in pp.childNodes) {
        var child = pp.childNodes[i];
        if (child != p) {
          child.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    p.style.display = "";
}
```

Comment: I would suggest u use JQuery for this kinda of coding. It would be a lot easier.

Comment: Please check the file attached. I want the focus on the li tag on click of that li tag but if i open another li tag that should hide the content of previous li tag. content is dsiplayed at bottom of the li tag which is clicked.